# Perl split array

Tags: arrays, perl, file, split

I'm new in Perl, I want to write a simple program which reads an input-file and count the letters of this file, this is my code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 $textfile = "example.txt";
 open(FILE, "< $textfile");

 @array = split(//,<FILE>);
 $counter = 0;
 foreach(@array){
      $counter = $counter + 1;
 }

 print "Letters: $counter";
```

this code shows me the number of letters, but only for the first paragraph of my Input-File, it doesn't work for more than one paragraph, can anyone help me, i don't know the problem =(
thank you

Answer (score 2):

- You only ever read one line.
- You count bytes (for which you could use [`-s`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)), not letters.

Fix:

```
my $count = 0;
while (<>) {
   $count += () = /\pL/g;
}
```

Comment: hm, I replaced the foreach-loop, with the while(<>) {$count += () ...... - loop, doesn't work, don't show me anything

Comment: @user3340823, in your case it'd be `while (<FILE>) ...`

Answer (score 1):

You code is a rather over-complicated way of doing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Always use these
use strict;
use warnings;

# Define variables with my
my $textfile = "example.txt";
# Lexical filehandle, three-argument open
# Check return from open, give sensible error
open(my $file, '<', $textfile) or die "Can't open $textfile: $!"

# No need for an array.
my $counter = length <$file>;

print "Letters: $counter";
```

But, as others have pointed out, you're counting *bytes* not *characters*. If your file is in ASCII or an 8-bit encoding, then you should be fine. Otherwise you should look at [perluniintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html).

Answer (score -1):

Here's an alternative aproach using a module to do the work ..

```
# the following two lines enforce 'clean' code
use strict;
use warnings;

# load some help (read_file)
use File::Slurp;

# load the file into the variable $text
my $text = read_file('example.txt');

#get rid of multiple whitespace and linefeed chars # ****
# and replace them with a single space             # ****
$text =~ s/\s+/ /;                                 # ****

# length gives you the length of the 'string' / scalar variable
print length($text);
```

you might want to comment out the lines marked '********' 
and play with the code...